# onfocus event getting called recursively in Apache wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I am understanding how to handle JS events like onfocus and onblur in apache wicket. I have a simple form in which there is a textfield. "onfocus" event on this I am trying to set the textfield to a value. I have observed on running the code  that onfocus is called again and again (recursively it seems). I fail to understand why and what I have done wrong.
Below is the code :

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<title>Wicket Examples - component reference</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form wicket:id="form">
    <INPUT wicket:id="input" type="text" name="input" style="WIDTH: 800px" />

</form>
```

Java:

```
package com.poc.pages;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.ChoiceRenderer;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

public class IndexPage extends WebPage
{
/**
 * Constructor
 */

public IndexPage()
{

    Form form = new Form("form");

    TextField<String> TextInput = new TextField<String>("input",Model.of(""));

    TextInput.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onfocus"){

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            String thisValue =
                    this.getComponent().getDefaultModelObjectAsString();
            thisValue = "ChangedNormally";
            this.getComponent().setDefaultModelObject("ChangedViaDefaultSetModel");
            target.add(this.getComponent());
            System.out.println("onfocus"+thisValue);
        }

    });

    form.add(TextInput);
   add(form);
}
}
```

When I focus on textfield here, ChangedViaDefaultSetModel is set and on console onfocusChangedNormally gets print continuously. I fail to undertsand few things :

1. Why does onfocus gets called again and again printing **onfocusChangedNormally** evertytime on console?
2. How can I get the value of actual model and not default model.
3. WHy does the normal value doesnot get reflected in model whereas on doing setDefaultModel() it works?

Thanks For Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This behavior, you implmented, is a little tricky. When you focus your `TextField` and add this component to the `target`, then AjaxRequest is updating it. When update is over, component must return its state, thats why focus gained and your behavior method `onUpdate` is called again.

To resolve this problem you must use some kind of blocking. The easiest way is to use `boolean` field and check if focus was already gained to prevent another update. (see the code below).

2) Second and third question is about models, and this is very large subject to discuss. You can learn more by reading [this](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/modelsforms.html) and [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models) articles, or "Wicket in Action" and "Wicket cookbook" books.

In my solution I used PropertyModel, that reflects the value of the field you set as a model of the `Component`. This code:`new PropertyModel<String>(this, "modelValue")` means that Wicket must search field with name "modelValue" in `this` (`IndexPage`) object and set as the model of `TextField`. That's why now you can only change this object field to set another value to `TextField` (don't forget to update component after that).

Comments for code:
 I have used `AjaxEventBehavior` but it's ok to use `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`.
 I have added `onblur` behavior to return old value of the `TextField` just to show possibilities of this solution.
 I have changed `TextInput` to `textInput` because [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) said so.

```
package com.poc.pages;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

public class IndexPage extends WebPage {
    private String modelValue = "ChangedNormally";
    private boolean focusGained = false;

    public IndexPage() {

        Form form = new Form("form");

        TextField<String> textInput = new TextField<String>("input", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "modelValue"));
        textInput.add(new AjaxEventBehavior( "onfocus" ) {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                if (!focusGained) {
                    modelValue = "ChangedViaDefaultSetModel";
                    target.add(this.getComponent());
                    focusGained = true;
                    System.out.println( "focus gained " + getComponent().getDefaultModelObject() );
                }
            }
        });
        textInput.add(new AjaxEventBehavior( "onblur" ) {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                modelValue = "ChangedNormally";
                target.add(this.getComponent());
                focusGained = false;
                System.out.println( "focus lost " + getComponent().getDefaultModelObject() );
            }
        });
        form.add(textInput);
        add(form);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.